# Traveling Salesman problem without restriction on the number of visits

Tags: algorithm, optimization, traveling-salesman

I have a problem similar to Traveling Salesman (TSP). I found some libraries to solve the Traveling Salesman problem. However, I would like to remove the restriction of visiting each city only once. How do I find the shortest path that visits each city *at least* once?

Comment: They edited the question in order to be better understood. What I would like to know is if in the problem of the traveling cashier I remove the restriction of each city being visited only once, will the algorithm provide me with the shortest path? How to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One simple way is through preprocessing. Replace each `c(i,j)` by the length/cost of the shortest path between i and j. Now apply standard tsp. When reporting, insert these shortest paths in the solution. This may result in cities being visited multiple times.